# Facebook Messenger Bot - How to use NodeJS to get User Information?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a bare bones chatbot in messenger set up and would like to expand on its potential functionality. The first thing I want to be able to do is access user info, mostly the users first name. I know this is possible, but as I am new to NodeJS I am not sure how to achieve this. I have not been able to find very many tutorials on chatbots past the intro stage. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is a link to an abbreviated version of my chatbot

This is the main bit of code that I think needs refining (see it below in the context of the rest of the bot)

```
function getName(event){
        request({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/" + sender,
        qs: {
            access_token : token,
            fields: "first_name"
        },
        method: "GET",

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error){
            console.log("error getting username")
        } else{
            var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body)
            name = bodyObj.first_name
            sendText(sender, "Hi, ")
            sendText(sender, name)
            sendText(sender, " whatsup?")
        }
    })
}
```

[Chatbot Code](https://pastebin.com/wGyHqMKv)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your input, what is your expected output? What isn't working right?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user (seems so as you got bodyObj.first_name )...

Comment: Thank you! And yes I have looked at a lot of their documentation. I just don't really know what it should look like (The GET request and how to save their name as a variable, etc.). Most of what I have is from tutorials. I get no response from the bot using the above code. Actually it oddly makes the bot respond more than once to each request but I am not sure how that could be.

Comment: My suggestion would be to step through your node.js using vscode and put breakpoints and inspect the objects to make sure they have your expected data and are being called when you think they're being called...

Comment: I can do that! So everything looks correct format wise though? The documentation doesn't provide NodeJS examples which has been throwing me off.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: 6.11.0 is my version

Comment: I mean it's very possible it should be something like bodyObj.user.first_name but I can't tell. You could use console.log(bodyObj) to find out, but I'd heavily suggest just getting vscode and using the debugger. Up to you.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I am back home, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jowens You could also consider a framework like Botpress (https://botpress.io) which handles this automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can get the facebook user info by below code:

```
  request({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/" + senderId + "?",
    qs: {
      access_token: config.FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'test-bot'
    },
    method: "GET",
    json: true,
    time: true
  }, 
  function(error, res, faceUserInfo) {
   console.log("faceUserInfo", faceUserInfo)
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your access token is correct.

I also suggest you check the what the error message is

```
console.log("error getting username", error);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sender is not defined in your function.**

It is being passed into your other functions, or delcared in the scope of your post request handler.

Make sure sender is defined, and your code should work fine.

Add the below line to your getName function:

`var sender = event.sender.id`

Answer (score -1):

Your variable name is not defined, should add let name=... and it works fine